# Get predecessor of document where condition in Firestore

Tags: android, google-cloud-firestore

in Firestore having something like :

```
{
 "customers" : [
   {
     "id" : 123,
     "users" : [
        {
          "id" : 1
        }
      ]
   },
   {
     "id" : 124,
     "users" : [
        {
          "id" : 2
        }
      ]
   },
  ]
}
```

How do i query the db to get the customer document having user with id = 1?

- customers is a collection and inside a customer document there is a
  users collection
- the query should return document of customer with id 123.

Comment: It's not clear what you're showing here.  Is "customers" a collection?  Or a field of a document in a collection?  What have you tried so far that doesn't work the way you expect?  The documentation on querying with a filter is pretty straightforward.  https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#simple_queries

Comment: yeah customers is a collection and inside a customer document there is a users collection

Comment: You just want to fetch documents where "id" is 1 ? What do you mean by predecessor?

Comment: What have you tried so far that doesn't work the way you expect?

Comment: @Dharmaraj maybe i want clear enough, please see edit

Comment: @DougStevenson i didnt see any example of such query in the docs, what i would do if i dont get better option is to add a collection that will help me index customers by user id but that seem like a workaround trying to avoid that

Comment: You should just be able to filter on the id field similar to what you see in the link I provided in the first comment.  All fields are indexed by default.

Comment: I dont think i can, because as i understand in order to get to the users collection i need to access a specific customer document, but i dont know which customer i should access thats exactly what i need to know

Comment: Instead of describing how your database looks like, please edit your question and add your database structure as a screenshot. Please respond with @AlexMamo